# Using linq to update a composite key field

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

In our SQL database we have a table with a composite key that includes fields we need to update from time to time. It's my understanding that, since we are using the Entity Framework, I need to remove the record from the database first then add the row back to the table.

Below is the simple method I created to handle an "update" since there are numerous methods that will be carrying this out. However, once the `.SaveChanges()` method is called after the `.Remove` I get the `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`:

```
Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of 
rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. 
Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong as I'm trying to remove the record, then perform the updates, then add the record back.

Here's the method that calls the remove/edit methods. When this method is called, the record hasn't been altered in any way shape or form yet.

```
    private static void ProcessAllChanges(ZipCodeIndex information, ZipCodeTerritory zipToUpdate)
    {
        try
        {
            RemoveRecord(zipToUpdate);

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(information.newTerritory)) zipToUpdate.IndDistrnId = information.newTerritory;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(information.newStateCode)) zipToUpdate.StateCode = information.newStateCode;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(information.newDescription)) zipToUpdate.DrmTerrDesc = information.newDescription;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(information.newChannelCode)) zipToUpdate.ChannelCode = information.newChannelCode;
            if (zipToUpdate.EndDate == DateTime.MinValue) zipToUpdate.EndDate = DateTime.MaxValue;

            EditRecord(zipToUpdate);
            _updated++;   
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            _msg += "Error during update; ";
            EventLog.WriteEntry("Monet", "Error during ProcessAllChanges: " + zipToUpdate.ToString() + " |EX| " + dbEx.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _msg += "Error during update; ";
            EventLog.WriteEntry("Monet", "Error during ProcessAllChanges: " + zipToUpdate.ToString() + " |MESSAGE| " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

And here are the two helper methods that get called

```
    public static void RemoveRecord(ZipCodeTerritory zipCode)
    {
        _db = new AgentResources();
        _db.ZipCodeTerritory.Attach(zipCode);
        _db.ZipCodeTerritory.Remove(zipCode);
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }

    public static void EditRecord(ZipCodeTerritory zipCode)
    {
        _db = new AgentResources();
        _db.ZipCodeTerritory.Add(zipCode);
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

**EDIT**

Based on a couple comments below I attempted to create a separate instance of the context object, however i received the same error using this method:

```
    public static void RemoveRecord(ZipCodeTerritory zipCode)
    {
        using (AgentResources deleteMe = new AgentResources())
        {
            deleteMe.ZipCodeTerritory.Attach(zipCode);
            deleteMe.ZipCodeTerritory.Remove(zipCode);
            deleteMe.SaveChanges();                
        }
    }
```

**Second Edit**

Here is the upper most method which calls the `ProcessAllChanges` method I posted above.

```
    public static string TerritoryOnly(ZipCodeIndex updateZip)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(updateZip.newEffectiveDate) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(updateZip.newEndDate))
        {
            return "Neither effective or end date can be present if updating Territory Code only; ";
        }

        RefreshProperties();

        foreach (var zipCode in updateZip.displayForPaging.Where(x => x.Update))
        {
            ProcessAllChanges(updateZip, zipCode);
        }

        _msg += _updated + " record(s) updated; ";

        return _msg;
    }
```

**Third Edit**

Per request here is the full class definition of `AgentResources`, our `DbContext` object

```
namespace Monet.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class AgentResources : DbContext
    {
        public AgentResources()
            : base("name=AgentResources")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public DbSet<AgentContEd> AgentContEd { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ContEdCourse> ContEdCourse { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Course> Course { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CourseToProduct> CourseToProduct { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Product { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProcessControl> ProcessControl { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AgentIdToTradingPartner> AgentIdToTradingPartner { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TradingPartner> TradingPartner { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Notes> Notes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CourseMaterials> CourseMaterials { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TransactionLog> TransactionLog { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Agent> Agent { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AgentIdentification> AgentIdentification { get; set; }
        public DbSet<BatchDashboard> BatchDashboard { get; set; }
        public DbSet<BatchPrograms> BatchPrograms { get; set; }
        public DbSet<FollowUpItems> FollowUpItems { get; set; }
        public DbSet<sysdiagrams> sysdiagrams { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AgentProductTraining> AgentProductTraining { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Channel> Channel { get; set; }
        public DbSet<RelationshipCodes> RelationshipCodes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<DropDownValues> DropDownValues { get; set; }
        public DbSet<QueueUpdates> QueueUpdates { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MarketingLookup> MarketingLookup { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TransmissionHistory> TransmissionHistory { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AgentTransmission> AgentTransmission { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ZipCodeTerritory> ZipCodeTerritory { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the `ZipCodeTerritory` class

```
public partial class ZipCodeTerritory
{
    public string ChannelCode { get; set; } //Composite key field
    public string DrmTerrDesc { get; set; }
    public string IndDistrnId { get; set; }
    public string StateCode { get; set; } //Composite key field
    public string ZipCode { get; set; } //Composite key field
    public System.DateTime? DisplayEndDate { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime EndDate { get; set; } //Composite key field
    public System.DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; } 
    public string LastUpdateId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastUpdateDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are leaving your context open `_db` but then calling the constructor each time in your helper methods `_db = new AgentResources();` why are you doing that? It's difficult to tell since you have left much of the code out. Is everything you have shown in the same class? Why are the methods `static`?

Comment: The methods are static because they're part of a public helper class. There are a number of updates that can occur on the web page so we decided to clean up the code by using a separate .cs file. These methods simply have the model object passed into it (`ZipCodeTerritory` model).

Comment: That's also why the context has the constructor called each time it's used. We want to make sure we're working with a clean slate each time and not something from a previous transaction.

Comment: If you want to work with a clean slate, you should just create the context in the method scope and dispose it.

Comment: Made an edit to the post showing the method i tried to use. Unfortunately this didn't work either.

Comment: Try calling `deleteme.DeleteObject(zipCode)` (instead of `Attach()` / `Remove()`) -- then `SaveChanges()`

Comment: Visual Studio tells me that the `System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Monet.Models.ZipCodeTerritory> does not contain a definition for 'DeleteObject'`

Comment: Can you try to use "deleteMe.Entry(zipCode).State = EntityState.Deleted;" instead of "...Remove()"?

Comment: The upper most method that I've posted gets called from within a `foreach` loop. Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: @NealR - `deleteme.DeleteObject(zipCode)` NOT `deleteme.ZipCodeTerritory.DeleteObject(zipCode)`

Comment: Are your sure all the properties representing a key into your database table are set properly before calling Attach/Remove?

Comment: If that doesn't work, can you check the exception type. Is it `OptimisticConcurrencyException` ?

Comment: @AirL: Yes, I just set a breakpoint at the `.Remove` line and did a successful SQL query based on object's values.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin: It is a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
public static void RemoveRecord(ZipCodeTerritory zipCode)
{
    using(var _newdb = new AgentResources())
    {
        ZipCodeTerritory zipCodeRemove = new ZipCodeTerritory();
        zipCodeRemove.channelCode = zipCode.channelCode;
        zipCodeRemove.stateCode = zipCode.stateCode;
        zipCodeRemove.zipCode= zipCode.zipCode;
        zipCodeRemove.endDate = zipCode.endDate;

        _newdb.ZipCodeTerritory.Attach(zipCodeRemove);
        _newdb.ZipCodeTerritory.Remove(zipCodeRemove);
        //((IObjectContextAdapter)_newdb).ObjectContext.Refresh(
                                                    // RefreshMode.ClientWins
                                                    //, zipCode);
        _newdb.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't recognize the `.Refresh` method or `RefreshMode` enum (I think?). Is there a namespace I need for this?

Comment: System.Data.Entity assembly - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896255.aspx

Comment: Weird, if I add the `System.Data.Objects` I get the `RefreshMode` but get nothing if I add the `System.Data.Entity`. $#&%^*@ Microsoft......

Comment: `System.Data.Objects` is the namespace. `System.Data.Entity` is the framework assembly. Microsoft naming in .Net is not always great, especially for newer framework classes. So did this work though?

Comment: Nope, even using `System.Data.Entity` I can't get VS to recognize `.Refresh`. I tried `System.Linq` too as MSDN says that contains  `DbContext.Refresh()` but no luck.

Comment: Can you include in your post the full class definition of `AgentResources` ? Also what version of .Net and what version of EF are you using?

Comment: We're using .Net 4.0 and EF 4.1. Appended the class definition to the post. Thx!

Comment: So I'm not longer getting an exception, and the code runs all the way through, however it's not actually removing the record from the database... thanks for your help btw

Comment: Can you include the code for `ZipCodeTerritory` and indicate which column or columns are a member of its primary (or unique) key?

Comment: Sorry about that, it's `channelCode`, `stateCode`, `zipCode`, and `endDate`

Comment: Still the same problem.... I think we're just going to ditch the entity framework and use .Net SQL connection objects instead. Thanks a lot for you help!